# How to add menu logout rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

I have read the rails admin documentation, but I can't find how to configure the top menu in rails admin.

I would like to add **logout** to the top menu in the admin panel

e.g./

Dashboard -  Home - **Logout**

Answer (score 8):

I'd imagine you're using devise?  If you are then add this to your rails_admin.rb

```
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```

within the config block

Comment: Good to hear @user3636123 :)  Please tick the answer that worked (best) for you.